# Whats the best way of converting a string to a double

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

So storing a `Price` property should be a decimal because when ever it comes to currecny it's best practice to use decimal (iirc)
How ever what my example here does is that it downloads a string that looks like this `$12.99`
What I could easily do is remove the first index of that string, and parse the rest as a double but using this example here makes it feel like its code smell.

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load("https://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/category/cat/cat-food/natural-cat-food");
            var titles = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class = 'product-name']/a[@title]");
            var prices = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class = 'product-price-promo']");

            foreach (var product in titles.Zip(prices,
                (t, p) => new Product {Name = t.InnerText.Trim(), Price = p.InnerText.Trim()}))
                Products.Add(product);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The Product Model is simple, just a name and a price property (I want to use decimal instead of string for the price that's kinda the goal here)

```
internal class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is, when doing something like this what is the proper way of converting `p.InnerText.Trim()` to a decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `decimal` type has a [`Parse` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91fwbcsb(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that allows you to specify that the string represents a currency-formatted number (which will account for the currency symbol and thousands separator), so can do something like this:

```
Price = decimal.Parse(p.InnerText.Trim(), NumberStyles.Currency));
```

Answer (score 3):

`public static double Parse(string input){
    double.Parse(input, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.Number);
}`